# Order: multiplying matrix by a scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say we have some matrix A and a constant c.

Does it generally hold that cA=Ac?

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Scalar_multiplication

Comment: Yes a scalar multiplication is commutative

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Matrix multiplication by scalar is commutative. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Scalar_multiplication